# What would cause a login to unexpectedly become a member of db_denydatareader?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

After months of working without issue a stored procedure began failing this morning with the error message:

```
SELECT permission was denied on the object 'XXX', database 'XXX', schema 'dbo'.
```

So I dutifully began tracing the issue through lost permissions on tables, views etc.
I eventually discovered that the login was now in the `db_denydatareader` role, but none of the people responsible for the database have made that change.
Are there any processes that could automatically make this change?
Is there anything I can do toprevent the change in the future?

Incidentally another 2 logins lost permissions on certain tables.

Comment: This would only happen if someone or something explicitly did it, so check your ETL processes, backup/restore processes, agent jobs, users with the power to do it, etc. Probably not anything we can help with. You can add auditing to keep an eye on this in the future, and follow the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) to reduce who/what could cause this to happen.

Comment: As part of the investigation, you can check the default trace for an eventclass of 110 which is "Audit Add Member to DB Role Event". This could help you narrow down who or what made the db_denydatareader membership change and when.